# Traversing all EnvDTE.CodeElement in the global/local scope

Tags: c#

Is it possible to traverse all the CodeElement objects in a given source file?

My real target is to be able to find out what is the type of a variable in the cursor position from a Visual Studio Add-in.. I have tried the following code:

```
// identify where the cursor is
TextSelection selection =
  (TextSelection)_applicationObject.ActiveWindow.Selection;
// get the starting point
EditPoint Start = selection.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint();
// get the element under the cursor
CodeElement element = _applicationObject.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.
   FileCodeModel.CodeElementFromPoint(Start,
   vsCMElement.vsCMElementVariable);

if (element.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementVariable)
{
    CodeVariable theVar = element as CodeVariable;
    string t = theVar.Type.AsString;
    MessageBox(t);
}
```

but it has some problems:

- It works only in a scope of a class, not in a function scope or global scope(in case of c++)
- It works when the cursor is in the position of the declaration, I want it to work when the cursor is in the position of a use of the variable.

So is there any way to get this semantic information without building my own compiler?